# office.js context.sync fails in the browser if a document has footnotes

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, office-addins

Link to project reproducing the bug:
https://github.com/dgrayling/forceSaveFailedBug/tree/main

Basically I try to load the document ooxml from a document with footnotes and it never returns from the await context.sync, the only thing that happens after more than a minute is:
POST https://word-edit.officeapps.live.com/we/OneNote.ashx?perfTag=ForceAutoSave_1%3BOoxmlSelection_1 net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED

Edit: This is strictly on Word online, this error does not occur on Mac Desktop.

Comment: Thanks for reaching us.
Can I know which platform(Word Desktop, Word Online, Mac or iOS) you are seeing this error ? And what's the word version ? it will be helpful for us to better understand your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, yes I should have clarified, this is the online version on Chrome. Notably it does not occur on the desktop versions. I presume the online version doesn't have a version number, its just latest but I can check that.

Comment: We can’t repro this. And according to the error you posted, it should be a network issue instead of product/service issue: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED, something happened to your network environment. Please double check!